# Change SDL background

Tags: c++, image, window, sdl

Is there any way to change the color of an empty SDL window to be white instead of black? I don't want to change any default settings. I'm just trying to change it for this particular program that I'm writing. I don't want to use an image file, but if I have to, I will.

I don't know if this matters, but I'm using `SDL_SetVideoMode()`

My code is very basic:

```
if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) == -1)
    return 1;

SDL_Surface * screen = NULL;

screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(width, height, bpp, SDL_SWSURFACE);

SDL_FillRect(screen, NULL, 0xFFFFFF);
SDL_Delay(3000);
```

Comment: Are you using OpenGL or pure SDL?

Comment: pure sdl. im just starting to learn sdl again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acquire the surface from your Window using `surf = SDL_SetVideoMode(...)` and then do

```
SDL_FillRect(surf, NULL, 0xFFFFFF); // 0xFFFFFF = white in RGB, NULL = full window
SDL_Flip(surf);
```

Comment: @calccrypto Show us some code then. Ideally a minimal example we could compile.

Answer (score 5):

You need to call [SDL_Flip](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_Flip) for your changes to show up.

Comment: For SDL 2.0, you need to use `SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(Window);`, as `SDL_Flip()` no longer exists.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [SDL_FillRect](http://www.libsdl.org/cgi/docwiki.cgi/SDL_FillRect) to fill the screen/a surface with your desired color.

Answer (score 3):

You need to call SDL_UpdateRect after SDL_FillRect.